# Designing forced-loss encounter for skilled level 1 group

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design, encounters

I'm designing an encounter for a skilled group of level 1s.  What I'm trying to do is set up a villain that the party would have to fight later; thus, this encounter is supposed to be a forced loss.  (Think the first Bowser battle from the original Paper Mario.)

My question is, how should I create this villain at so that he looks beatable but, even with the players' skill, he is not and a wipe would be guaranteed?  Thanks!

EDIT: There are five players in the group: a paladin, a monk, a barbarian, a cleric, and a ranger.

Comment: How exactly do you define "looks beatable"? Do your NPCs have their levels tattooed somewhere so PC can see them?

Comment: No, they don't.  Their HP levels are visible to the group, but their character levels are not.

Comment: FYI, the close votes on this question were split, it wasn't just closed as opinion based despite the message. 2 were for "unclear", 1 for "too broad", 2 for "primarily opinion based". But close messages only pick up one reason. I voted to close as unclear myself, because what you're describing involves *far* more than just picking a level. We do not know what your party composition is like, which is necessary for evaluating challenge. We also do not know what the villain is like, despite the fact we're being asked to pick a level for them.

Comment: Ah.  I guess I just didn't give enough information; I apologize for that.

Comment: @PSDuckie this is a good specific question that gets at the "art" of adventure/encounter design, which is why many feel it is opinion dominated. Perhaps a better way to phrase it would be: what empirical methods or tools are available for simulating encounters to create a desired probability of success? The CR tables are one method (and they are fairly conservative), but there are others (some involving numerical simulation).

Comment: I've learned about the CR tables being conservative firsthand.  Thank you for the suggestion on rephrasing.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open because this addresses DM mechanics specifically. In my opinion, the question is very clear: He wants to know how to design an encounter that will keep the villain alive even if the party finds a way to outsmart him. Many DM's run into this kind of problem, and I for one have some very examples of tools he can use to help him with something like this that are not opinion based.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli I agree that there's a core, answerable question in here and have voted to reopen. I would like to see OP edit the question from "what level should I create this villain..." to something like "how do I create this villain...?" Asking what *level* presupposes much of the answers, I believe.

Comment: It would help if you would at least explain how many characters are in the group and what classes they are playing.

Comment: nitsua60, I put in the edit you suggested.  

KorvinStarmast, There are five players (not counting myself as the DM) in the group.  I don't remember offhand what classes they've picked but I'll let you know as soon as I get a reminder of that.  

Lino Frank Ciaralli, you are absolutely correct in what I am asking.

Comment: And as for the group composition, we have a paladin, a monk, a barbarian, a cleric, and a ranger.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into the question; comments get deleted.

Comment: Didn't realize that; the clarification has been edited into the question.

Comment: @PSDuckie - I would recommend reposting the question with your edits so that it can be addressed. It doesn't look like people are paying attention to reopening this, despite your major modifications that make it completely addressable.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli Thanks.  I think I'm going to leave this question be, though.  The one answer I got appears to be enough to help me get started designing this encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make the villain some kind of sorcerer so he doesn't necessarily has a lot of HP.
- Have him confront the party while the party has some helper NPCs (guards e.g.).
- Have him pull out an unexpected magic protection, a group of supporters and/or a devastating attack spell which would wipe out the helper NPCs at an opportune moment.

What this should accomplish is:

- Make him look beatable as far as players are concerned.
- Demonstrate his power while not wiping the player characters (see Dungeon World: Announce future Badness).
- Give the players a clue that a retreat would be wise.
- Give them a hint to how they can stack the next encounter in their favor (not let the villain's mooks ambush then, find countermeasure against his magical attack/defense).

Comment: Very similar to my answer so I will add differences here.  I like to have the NPC companion fight one small fight with them in the hall outside the "boss room" and have them decimate low level enemies.  Then, the players can see how strong the companion is, then see how easily they are taken down by the boss.  That gives them a good context for the boss' power level.

Comment: @CalvinSmith If you have an answer that differs, even slightly, you should add it as an answer instead of commenting on someone else's.  Comments are ephemeral; answers are not.  Of course, don't do that now because the question is on hold until we get further clarification from the querent.

Comment: I'd somewhat caution against a caster... they can end up being glass cannons. I like some of the ideas you have though... maybe have the bad guy destroy an NPC that is super powerful? like the players have seen this NPC just destroy bad guys, then BOOM, he get's one-shot.

Comment: @Jeff The idea comes from the Dungeon World rules. They are intentionally informally written and can be read as a book of GM advice. The main thing is the GM making "soft moves" like "Announce Future Badness" or "Announce Distant Badness" and then following up with "hard moves" like "Inflict Harm" or "Take Their Stuff Away".